# How do I create a special link so that the user who clicked on that link can access a certain registration page?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using Swift mailer to generate a email that gets sent to the user when the admin user creates an account for that user. I want that email to contain a link that leads to a account registration page which only that user can access.

What do I have to do to make the registration page only accessible to that user?

Answer (score 0):

The page will always be accessible to any user (as it will be a GET request if clicked through the mail link), so the trick is to make it a difficult URL for a regular visitor to find. Simply create a random string of your choice (preferably uniquely-correlated to each user in the database) and **append** it to the page you want the user to visit:

```
$id = rand(1, 100000); // Grab the unique string from your database here
echo "<a href='page.php?id='" . $id . ">Registration link</a>";
```

Then, to check if this ID variable is set when someone accesses the page, you can check the `$_GET` parameter:

```
if(isset($_GET['id'] && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
  // Code here will be executed on any ID in page.php?id=[any]
}
```

If you want to check for a **specific** string, you can use:

```
$id = 1337;
if($_GET['id'] == $id) {
  // Code here will only trigger when visiting page.php?id=1337
}
```

You can also check if a **particular** user is visiting the page, by setting checking that the logged-in user's ID matches the `$_GET` parameter:

```
$id = '' // Grab the user's ID from your database here
if(isset($_GET['id'] && !empty($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id'] == $id) {
  // Code here should be written based on the user being logged in
}
```

There's unfortunately no way to stop someone 'guessing' that you have code pertaining to an ID `$_GET`, as E-mails can't open links in `POST`. Restricting the content based on a **specific** `GET` request is your best bet, as someone will have difficulty guessing the exact value the parameter needs.

For your specific situation, you should be perfectly fine just using something like the `1337` code above. Simply set the `<a href>` link in the E-mail to use that specific value.

Hope this helps! :)